How to find salaries of their subordinates
This is my data ,



employee_id
name
manager_id
salary




1
Alice

100000.00


2
Bob
1
80000.00


3
Charlie
1
75000.00


4
David
2
60000.00


5
Eve
2
50000.00


6
Frank
3
55000.00



Question is The total salary paid under each employee (including their own salary and all the salaries of their subordinates, directly or indirectly).
I tried hierarchical way and achieved below result.



employee_id
name
manager_id
salary
path
total_salary




1
Alice

100000.00
boss
100000


2
Bob
1
80000.00
boss->Bob
180000


3
Charlie
1
75000.00
boss->Charlie
175000


4
David
2
60000.00
boss->Bob->David
240000


5
Eve
2
50000.00
boss->Bob->Eve
230000


6
Frank
3
55000.00
boss->Charlie->Frank
230000



but my expectation is for Alice should be 430000.00,Bob ->190000.00,Charlie ->



employee_id
name
manager_id
salary
path
total_salary




1
Alice
NULL
100000.00
boss
430000.00


2
Bob
1
80000.00
boss->Bob
190000.00


3
Charlie
1
75000.00
boss->Charlie
130000.00


4
David
2
60000.00
boss->Bob->David
60000.00


5
Eve
2
50000.00
boss->Bob->Eve
50000.00


6
Frank
3
55000.00
boss->Charlie->Frank
55000.00




"I tried hierarchical way " what was the code?

I tried using recursive SQL

@LearnHadoop, you need to show your query. recursive SQL could mean a lot of things

You calculated the total salary paid to each employee (including his own salary and all salaries of his supervisors). Summarize in a similar recursion from each employee   to all of his subordinates (including his own salary and all salaries of his subordinates). Path should be like Frank->Charlie->boss, Charlie->boss, boss.

Output (1,Alice,NULL,100000.00,'boss', 430000.00) there should be 420 000?

Please edit your question to provide a [mcve]. Right now it's only some data and requirements, with no attempt of your own. And "using recursive SQL" and "tried hierarchical way" doesn't help.

This can be done with a recursive cte to find all the subordinates for each person in the employee table and then their salaries merely need to be summed to calculate the total salary.
create table employee (
    employee_id integer primary key,
    name varchar not null,
    manager_id integer,
    salary integer not null
    );

insert into employee (employee_id, name, manager_id, salary)
values (1, 'Alice', null, 100000),
(2, 'Bob', 1, 80000),
(3, 'Charlie', 1, 75000),
(4, 'David', 2, 60000),
(5, 'Eve', 2, 50000),
(6, 'Frank', 3, 55000);


with recursive cte (apex_id, employee_id, salary) as (
    select employee_id, employee_id, salary
    from employee
    union all
    select cte.apex_id, employee.employee_id, employee.salary
    from cte
    join employee on employee.manager_id = cte.employee_id
    )
select employee.*, sum(cte.salary) as total_salary
from cte
join employee on employee.employee_id = cte.apex_id
group by employee.employee_id
order by employee.employee_id;


The OP provided no detail at all - no [mcve] - just data. Please don't write custom code for someone's requirements.


For each employee (root_id) recursively collect all their subordinates, directly or indirectly.
There we save root id for employee and join other rows of hierarchy tree in recursion.

from r inner join Salaries t on t.manager_id=r.employee_id

We get (for Alice) Alice as child  of level 1, Charlie and Bob as childs of level 2...



lvl
root_id
root_name
employee_id
name
salary
path




1
1
Alice
1
Alice
100000
Alice


2
1
Alice
3
Charlie
75000
Alice->Charlie


2
1
Alice
2
Bob
80000
Alice->Bob


3
1
Alice
5
Eve
50000
Alice->Bob->Eve


3
1
Alice
4
David
60000
Alice->Bob->David


3
1
Alice
6
Frank
55000
Alice->Charlie->Frank



For Bob



lvl
root_id
root_name
employee_id
name
salary
path




1
2
Bob
2
Bob
80000
Bob


2
2
Bob
5
Eve
50000
Bob->Eve


2
2
Bob
4
David
60000
Bob->David



Charly



lvl
root_id
root_name
employee_id
name
salary
path




1
3
Charlie
3
Charlie
75000
Charlie


2
3
Charlie
6
Frank
55000
Charlie->Frank



For David



lvl
root_id
root_name
employee_id
name
salary
path




1
4
David
4
David
60000
David



And others



lvl
root_id
root_name
employee_id
name
salary
path




1
5
Eve
5
Eve
50000
Eve


1
6
Frank
6
Frank
55000
Frank




Aggregate all salaries for root_id.

See example



employee_id
name
manager_id
salary




1
Alice
null
100000


2
Bob
1
80000


3
Charlie
1
75000


4
David
2
60000


5
Eve
2
50000


6
Frank
3
55000



with  recursive 
  r as(
  select 1 lvl,employee_id, name, manager_id, salary
     ,employee_id as root_id,name as root_name,manager_id root_manager_id,salary root_salary
     ,cast(concat(name,'') as varchar(100)) path
  from Salaries
  union all
  select lvl+1 lvl,t.employee_id, t.name, t.manager_id, t.salary
     ,r.root_id,r.root_name,root_manager_id,root_salary
     ,cast(concat(r.path,'->',t.name)  as varchar(100)) path
  from r inner join Salaries t on t.manager_id=r.employee_id
)
select root_id employee,min(root_name) name,min(root_manager_id)manager_id
  ,min(root_salary) salary
  ,sum(salary) total_salary
  ,string_agg(r.path,',') tot_path
from r
group by root_id
order by root_id




employee_id
name
manager_id
salary
total_salary
tot_path




1
Alice
null
100000
420000
Alice,Alice->Bob,Alice->Charlie,Alice->Bob->David,Alice->Bob->Eve,Alice->Charlie->Frank


2
Bob
1
80000
190000
Bob,Bob->David,Bob->Eve


3
Charlie
1
75000
130000
Charlie,Charlie->Frank


4
David
2
60000
60000
David


5
Eve
2
50000
50000
Eve


6
Frank
3
55000
55000
Frank



fiddle
Minimize query, excluding code part for debugging and clarity
with  recursive r as(
  select employee_id as root_id,name as root_name,manager_id root_manager_id,salary root_salary
     ,employee_id, salary
  from Salaries
  union all
  select r.root_id,r.root_name,root_manager_id,root_salary
     ,t.employee_id, t.salary
  from r inner join Salaries t on t.manager_id=r.employee_id
)
select root_id,min(root_name) name,min(root_manager_id)manager_id
  ,min(root_salary) salary
  ,sum(salary) total_salary
from r
group by root_id

If you want get all columns from  your table and only add totals column
with  recursive r as(
  select employee_id as root_id ,employee_id, salary
  from Salaries
  union all
  select r.root_id ,t.employee_id, t.salary
  from r inner join Salaries t on t.manager_id=r.employee_id
)
select s.*,t.total_salary
from salaries s 
inner join (
     select root_id,sum(salary) total_salary
     from r
     group by root_id
  ) t  on t.root_id=s.employee_id


The OP provided no detail at all - no [mcve] - just data. Please don't write custom code for someone's requirements.
